# Why Desktop PIDL's size is zero?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I have a question about Desktop PIDL.

I got the Desktop PIDL using `SHGetDesktopFolder` and `IPersistFolder2::GetCurFolder.`

But, I check this using ILIsEmpty, return true.

So, I check Desktop PIDL, and cbSize in PIDL is zero.

Why Desktop PIDL's size is zero??

Comment: I guess it would be useful to see your code, specifically a [mcve].

Comment: I'd get the desktop PIDL using [SHGetKnownFolderIDList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetknownfolderidlist), as without some code, I can't see an obvious path from SHGetDesktopFolder -> IPersistFolder2 to a PIDL.

Comment: The PIDL for the desktop is empty, by design.

Comment: The desktop is the root of the namespace, a bit like "\" for physical paths. Corollary: any absolute PIDL is relative to the desktop PIDL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[If this PIDL is empty, the parent folder is the desktop.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/ns-shlobj_core-cida)

You can check if its name is "Desktop" using [`GetDisplayNameOf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ishellfolder-getdisplaynameof).

```
IShellFolder *psfDesktop = NULL;
hr = SHGetDesktopFolder(&psfDesktop);
IPersistFolder2 *pf = NULL;
hr = psfDesktop->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IPersistFolder2), (void**)(&pf));
PIDLIST_ABSOLUTE pidl = NULL;
hr = pf->Initialize(pidl);
hr = pf->GetCurFolder(&pidl);
BOOL result = ILIsEmpty(pidl);
STRRET name;
psfDesktop->GetDisplayNameOf(pidl, SHGDN_NORMAL, &name);
```